# KIVY: How do I make a button to initiate my Paint app

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I have a working Kivy code as given below. I am able to draw random shapes once I run it. Now, I want to enable drawing only after clicking the Hello button once. How should I modify my code?

Python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line


class Painter(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line( points = (touch.x, touch.y))
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main3.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name:"main"
    FloatLayout:
        Painter
        Button:
            text: "Hello"
            font_size: 50
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making a new screen for painting.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line


KV = '''
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
    PaintScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name:"main"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Go paint"
            font_size: 50
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'paint'

<PaintScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'paint'
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Exit painting"
            font_size: 40
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'main'
        Painter:
'''


class Painter(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line( points = (touch.x, touch.y))
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: But, the major issue is that I want to put many such buttons here, for various functions such as drawing straight line, a rectangle, a circle etc. Will I be able to do all such functions in a single screen? Bdw, thanks for the reply!

Comment: @thechargedneutron yea you can do that. Your current painter class just draw a freestyle line. You could change those methods. So they just get the points. Then let the buttons decide what they should do. draw rectangle or whatever you want. Since you dont really ask about that in your question, I dont think i should edit my answer. You only asked about enabling the drawing function. But again, it is possible to make all that in one screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the a toggle button and link its state to the Painter:

```
    ...
    Painter:
        hello_active: hello_button.state == 'down'
    ToggleButton:
        id: hello_button
        text: "Hello"
        font_size: 50
        color: 0,1,0,1
        size_hint: 0.3,0.2
        pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}
```

and in the python file...

```
class Painter(Widget):

    hello_active = BooleanProperty(False)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if not self.hello_active:
            return #nothing to see here ...
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line( points = (touch.x, touch.y))
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if 'line' in touch.ud:
            touch.ud["line"].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
```

Comment: So I modified my code, but I am getting an error like this:
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"
Can you please find out the problem with my code

Comment: Maybe the error is because of not importing certain packages. Can you please list out the additional header file that I will need in the above snipet. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: using hello_active=BooleanProperty(True) instead of false helped me to resolve the issue. I am not sure how the difference in True and False causes the error but the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot!!